# angular custom filter only on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular custom filters and I was wondering if there was any way to apply the filters to an ng-repeat only when a button is clicked.

Here is a jsfiddle for an example :

http://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/53Xuk/

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="PersonCtrl as person">
        <input type="text" ng-model="letter" placeholder="Enter a letter to filter">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | startsWithLetter:letter">
                {{ friend }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometings like this:

```
function MyController(startsWithLetterFilter) {
    //retrieve person object        
    this.friends = person.friends;

    this.onclick = function() {
        this.friends = startsWithLetterFilter(person.friends, myLetter);
    }
}
```

Bind the repeater to the friends property and not directed to person.friends so you can manipulate the array responding on some events